# Would birds be able to fly if the air had no viscosity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

There are already many answers to the general question of why birds or planes can fly. But my question is more specific: I would like to understand the relative importance of the viscosity. The air has a very low viscosity, so I am wondering whether it really makes a difference that the viscosity is non-zero. Or could a bird fly in a non-viscous fluid?

Comment: Please let us know if the link adequately address your question. That proposed dupe target only talks about fixed wings, not flexible flapping bird wings.

Comment: The proposed dupe also discusses it from a very different perspective (why an inviscid theory gives a value for lift) -- the top level takeaway is the same, "lift cannot exist without viscosity," but there might be some additional points to bring up in an answer to this question.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! The link almost addresses my question. I would have wished a more intuitive answer, but it's already good!